# PowerShell: Ending MS-Word-Process takes pretty long

Tags: microsoft-word, powershell

With a PowerShell-Script I am opening all .docx Files in a certain path and update the Table of Contents of each document - all executed step by steap (`ForEach`).

After the Table of Contents of any document was updated, the updated document will be saved, then closed and as a last step the Word-application should be quitted again.

The Word-window (`$word.Visible = $true`) closes immediately, however, the process of WINWORD.EXE remains active (seen in Task Manager) for about 3 up to 5 minutes after.

Can somebody explain me why that is the case? I expected that `$word.Quit()` would also end the process of WINWORD.EXE immediately.

Is there any trick to end the WINWORD.EXE immediately? The script is executed with Windows Task Scheduler on Windows Server 2016.

The relevant part of my code:

```
$FileList = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ExportedDocuments -File -Filter "*.docx"
ForEach ($DocFile in $FileList) {
    
        $DocFileName = $DocFile.Name.split(".")[0]
        
        Write-Log -Message "The document: $DocFileName is being processed" -Path $LogFile -Level Info

        $word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
        $word.Visible = $true
        $doc = $word.Documents.Open($DocFile.FullName)
        $toc = $doc.TablesOfContents
        $toc.item(1).update()
        $doc.save()
        $doc.close()

        Remove-Variable toc
        Remove-Variable doc

        Write-Log -Message "Before word.Quit()" -Path $LogFile -Level Info
        # CleanUp
        $word.Quit()
        $null = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$word)
        [gc]::Collect()
        [gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        Remove-Variable word
        
        Write-Log -Message "After word.Quit()" -Path $LogFile -Level Info
}
```

The relevant part of log written:

```
2020-06-17 11:09:10 INFO: Before word.Quit() 
2020-06-17 11:13:27 INFO: After word.Quit()
```

As a first solution to speed up the closing of the process I have embedded following to my script, just after `$word.quit()`

```
    $ProcessActive = Get-Process WINWORD -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if($ProcessActive -eq $null)
    {
     Write-Log -Message "WINWORD process was already closed" -Path $LogFile -Level Info
    }
    else
    {
     Stop-Process -processname "WINWORD"
     Write-Log -Message "WINWORD was still running and has been stopped by the script" -Path $LogFile -Level Info
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning up your references $toc, $doc after you have closed the document but before calling $word.Quit(), it can take a while for objects to be cleaned up automatically. You might find that is contributing to the delay in the Word instance actually closing down. If you have a lot of docs then your code could be optimising by creating the Word instance outside of your loop instead of creating and destroying it for each file.

Comment: Hello Enigman, thanks, I will give it a try. The script progresses round about three documents per run (it is currently executed once per day). In future it may go up to 10-20 documents per day.

Comment: Is it enought to include `Remove-Variable toc` and `Remove-Variable doc` before `$word.quit()`? I have tried that - it doesnt seem to have any effect on the performance. I have updated the script on my question with the two lines.